# Rooms availiability and Allocation

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a room booking system, The system is suppose to check if the room is not full before allocating a user to the room. 
I want to book a user to a room randomly with efficient mysql query.

I have two tables

```
Rooms Details
rID     |   Room Number     |   No of persons   |
 1      |   Room23          |       2           |
 2      |   Room24          |       1           |


Allocated Users

rID*    |   user Name   |
 1      |     manueis   |
```

How can I check if the `room23` is left with a person and then setting the next user to the room.

Comment: Set a status on the room and query the table for room that is available and the number of pax it can have

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you want your return resultset to look like.

To get the rooms along with the number of "allocated users", you run a query like this.

```
SELECT r.rid
     , r.no_of_persons
     , COUNT(p.rid) AS no_allocated 
  FROM room_detail r
  LEFT
  JOIN allocated_user p
    ON p.rid = r.rid
 GROUP
    BY r.rid
     , r.no_of_persons
```

If you want to exclude rows that already have a count of "allocated_user" that is not less than "no_of_persons" for the room, you could add a HAVING clause...

```
HAVING r.no_of_persons > COUNT(p.rid)
```

As far as ordering that result, you can add an `ORDER BY` clause. To get the "fullest" rooms first, with the largest "no_of_persons"

```
ORDER
   BY r.no_of_persons - COUNT(p.rid) ASC
    , r.no_of_persons DESC
```

or, as your question suggests, if you want those rows ordered in a pseudo-random fashion, you could make (inefficient) use of the `RAND()` function...

```
ORDER
   BY RAND()
```

(That can be inefficient because the RAND() function has to be evaluated for every row returned, and then all of the rows have to be sorted by the value returned by that function.

If you only want a single row returned, you can add a LIMIT clause...

```
LIMIT 1
```